# How to Identify RGB codes in a PDF document

Tags: pdf, colors, adobe, rgb

I'm looking for some advice on how to get started on a project my team is working on internally. The basic situation is this:

We receive PDF's that are 250-500 pages in length. Some of those pages (let's say, 10-15 of them) may have color on them. Of those 10-15 pages, some might need to remain in color. if it is identified that none need to be printed in color, we print in black and white. Otherwise we print color.

Currently we tab through each of those pages to find pages with color. As you can imagine, this is very time consuming. I am looking to build a solution that perhaps will output page numbers (as an example) of pages with color so the end user can simply jump to the page being referenced and make a determination. I am not sure where to start on this and i'm looking for some advice.

Comment: For which programming environment are you searching a solution?

Comment: There are commercial solutions that do just that.